# Создание анимированной кнопки из gif

Tags: css3, вёрстка, анимация, gif

Добрый вечер всем! Я только начал изучать программирование и верстку сайтов, и сейчас я столкнулся с такой проблемой. На сайтах нашел такую гифку кноки: [image: gif изображение] И хотел бы сделать такую же на сайте. Но не сильно понимаю как это сверстать. Можно ли как-нибудь, разбив изображение по кадрам, сделать так чтобы кнопка на сайте анимировалась после клика пользователем? Как это в коде будет прописано? Нужно это делать через @keyframes, анимацию или переходы? Или как? Спасибо за ответы заранее!

Comment: Лучше в svg сделать

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна только кнопочка лав, то можно сделать кнопку с обесцвеченным изображением. И при наведении показывать заранее спрятаную гифку, наложенную поверх display: visible.

А если по правильному то анимация через @keyframes, но тут нужен опыт, не так то просто сделать хорошую анимацию.